# How do I set image visible if case is met?

Tags: ms-access

I have a report I'm trying to create. One of the options in the form is Symbol with a dropbox for users to select X, /, or -

If the X is visible, I want the respective image (large red version of symbol) to be visible.

I have built event on Report Load:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

Select Case Me.Symbol

    Case "X"
        Me.ImageX.Visible = True
        Me.ImageDash.Visible = False
        Me.ImageDiagonal.Visible = False
    Case "-"
        Me.ImageX.Visible = False
        Me.ImageDash.Visible = True
        Me.ImageDiagonal.Visible = False
    Case "/"
        Me.ImageX.Visible = False
        Me.ImageDash.Visible = False
        Me.ImageDiagonal.Visible = True
    Case Else
        Me.ImageX.Visible = True
        Me.ImageDash.Visible = True
        Me.ImageDiagonal.Visible = True

End Select

End Sub
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Use report Detail Format event.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by June, use the `On Format` event for the relevant section in which the objects reside, as the various object references do not hold values until after the `On Load` event of the report. For more information regarding the order of events, you may wish to refer to [this documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9#bm5).

I might also suggest condensing your code to the following:

```vb
Private Sub Detail_Format()
    Me.ImageX.Visible = Me.Symbol = "X"
    Me.ImageDash.Visible = Me.Symbol = "-"
    Me.ImageDiagonal.Visible = Me.Symbol = "/"
End Sub
```

Comment: Exact code I was thinking of suggesting but you beat me. Keep in mind Format event only executes for PrintPreview or direct to printer, not ReportView.